# Turning python object with special character to JSON string object

Tags: python, json, special-characters, backslash, rawstring

I have gone through a lot of examples in stack overflow that are related to this kind of issue but none of those answers worked for my problem. I have a string inside a variable which contains the escape single backslash character "\". I am concatenating that string variable to a JSON string variable. Then doing json.loads() on that json string but I am getting an error:

```
ValueError: Expecting , delimiter: line 1 column 41 (char 40)
```

This is my code:

```
import json 

# The string of pass_string is taken from a rest/api/content of a website
pass_string = "I am an \"Engineer\""
data = '{"data": {"test": 1, "hello": "' + pass_string + ' in this lifetime."}, "id": 4}'

json_data = json.loads(data)
print(json_data)
```

Since pass_string is taken from a request.get() function from a website it is not possible to turn that into a raw string and then input into our data like:

```
pass_string = r"I am an \"Engineer\""
```

The above does work but my string is being passed inside the variable pass_string so I would have to modify the contents inside the variable somehow. Tried a lot of examples from stack overflow but none seem to work for my case.

Comment: It's is almost never a good idea to directly try to create a JSON string. Instead, use a `dict` to manipulate the data structure then serialize that to JSON

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Even if I use a dict to input serilaized data to JSON that would still mean that the pass_string will have that backslash and that would still cause my code to fail

Comment: What is it you *are actually trying to accomplish*? What are your exact inputs? And no, if you *serialize* from a `dict` of strings, it **won't cause an error**.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I am trying to use a response.put() method to pass that json_data payload into the website and so the actual pass_string is some kind of html code with backslashes which is not making the data into a JSON type data and for request.put() method the payload has to be of JSON type

Comment: OK, **but why are you trying to manually construct the json**? Instead, create a dict, then serialize the dict. You said "I am concatenating that string variable to a JSON string variable. " What is the "json string variable"?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Oh I see. This was the original JSON string variable: data = '{"id":"525424594","type":"page", "title":"Feature Automation - POST data","space":{"key":"FW"},"body":{"storage":{"value":"' + pass_string + '","representation":"storage"}}, "version":{"number":21}}'

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I am trying to input this into a requests.put() method like: response = requests.put('https://confluence.ai.com/rest/api/content/525424594', headers=headers, data=data, auth=HTTPBasicAuth('svc-Auto@ai.com', 'gineering1@ai'))

Comment: **No** That is not the original string, you are doing `+ pass_string +`. What is the actual string you are working with?? EDIT: see my answer

Comment: <p><br /></p><table><colgroup><col /><col /><col /><col /><col /><col /></colgroup><tbody><tr><th><p>JIRA</p></th><th><p>Type</p></th><th><p>PR</p></th><th><p>Commit</p></th><th><p>Author</p></th><th><p>Date</p></th></tr><tr><td><p><a href=\"https://cejira.ai.com/browse/IAP-5742\">

Comment: Stop posting this stuff **in the comments**. In any case, see my answer. I think you just didn't understand what I was telling you to do.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

`json.loads` needs a string representation of the escape, so you need to escape the escape:

```
import json 

pass_string = "I am an \"Engineer\"".replace('\"', '\\"')
data = '{"data": {"test": 1, "hello": "' + pass_string + ' in this lifetime."}, "id": 4}'

json_data = json.loads(data)
print(json_data)
```

Output:

```
{'data': {'test': 1, 'hello': 'I am an "Engineer" in this lifetime.'}, 'id': 4}
```

Comment: YESS!!! Thank You so much. Toiled hard on this and looked at countless solutions but you had the perfect solution that worked.

Comment: This is not a solution which you can put to work in runtime.

Answer (score -1):

Just stop trying to create JSON strings manually. That is your fundamental problem. Use *the python data structures* then *serialize that to the string at the end using the `json` module*.

So start with something like:

```
>>> import json
>>> data = {"data": {"test": 1, "hello": " in this lifetime."}, "id": 4}
```

Then simply:

```
>>> pass_string = "I am an \"Engineer\""
>>> data['data']['hello'] = pass_string + data['data']['hello']
>>> print(data)
{'data': {'test': 1, 'hello': 'I am an "Engineer" in this lifetime.'}, 'id': 4}
>>> print(json.dumps(data))
{"data": {"test": 1, "hello": "I am an \"Engineer\" in this lifetime."}, "id": 4}
```

Although, since you are passing it to `requests.put` as the `data` argument, you don't have to use `json.dumps` at all... You haven't been very clear, I **think** you actually start with a JSON string,

```
data = '{"data": {"test": 1, "hello": " in this lifetime."}, "id": 4}'
```

So what you *should* do is just:

```
data = json.loads(data)
data['data']['hello'] = pass_string + data['data']['hello']
```

And voilá. You can now just do `requests.put(url,data=data)`

Comment: I tried this but I got an error while executing the requests.put() method. Then I tried to see the content of my JSON by doing print(data) and saw that all the elements of the JSON are in terms of unicode as in u'test': u'1' but except for my pass)string which is something like u'pass_string_key': 'pass_string->contents' so basically it is not in terms of unicode and json.loads() is giving an error TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: @Ashish what? Are you on Python 2??? You **really need to provide a [mcve]**. If you don't accurately  and completely describe your problem, we cannot help you.

Comment: @Ashish **and stop putting code/error messages in comments**. Edit your quesiton to add these details as *formatted text*

Comment: Thank you for the advice. The solution given by RJ Adriaansen worked for me